# Entity Framework6 Code First Many To Many select always null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a Many to Many relationship set up such that in my context I have;

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){

      modelBuilder.Entity<Module>().HasMany(m => m.Questions).WithMany()
          .Map(q =>
            {
                q.ToTable("Modules_And_Questions");
                q.MapLeftKey("ModuleId");
                q.MapRightKey("QuestionId");
            });

      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  }

  public virtual DbSet<Module> Modules { get; set; }
  public virtual DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
```

executing

```
_context.Modules.Where(m => m.ModuleId == 3);
```

will return me the appropriate module, but the questions element is null. (Checking this in the database shows that there are 40 questions for module 3.)

A breakpoint shows that OnModelCreating is being hit. Though if it helps, I have noticed that mis-spelling any of the elements in quotes within the model builder does not cause an error, so I have my doubts that I am calling / setting this up correctly.

So why is Questions Null, when it should contain a list of 40 Question elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not happen on its own. You must tell EF that you *want* to load the questions by using `Include`:

```
_context.Modules.Include(m => m.Questions).Where(m => m.ModuleId == 3);
```

If the `Module.Questions` property is marked as `virtual` (see Kaf's example) it should work as well. The questions will be loaded as soon as you access the `Module.Questions` property. However, this will be a second database query while when using `Include` the questions will be queried together with the modules in a single database request.

Comment: If I use the syntax you propose I get an error, "Cannot Convert Lambda expression to type 'string'".
However using Include("Questions") works. So should your syntax work and I am missing somethign?

Comment: @Matt: For the lambda version of `Include` you must add `using System.Data.Entity;` to your code file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added Question as a collection to the Module class? Try this

```
public class Medule
{

    //Constructor   
    public Medule()
    {
        Questions = new HashSet<Question>();
    }

    //List of Module properties
    public ModuleId {get; set;}


    //Question
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I hadn't instantiated the collection in the constructor, though I had the property. That means that I no longer have a null collection of questions, but it still doesnt populate.